# How to add two conditions in merge statement using rowid and rownum

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

```
CREATE SEQUENCE e_demo2_tab_sq;

CREATE TABLE e_demo2_tab 
(
    tab_id   NUMBER(10) DEFAULT e_demo2_tab_sq.nextval NOT NULL,
    e_id     NUMBER(10),
    e_uuid   NUMBER(10),
    seq_cnt  NUMBER(10)
);

INSERT INTO e_demo2_tab VALUES(e_demo2_tab_sq.nextval, 11, 13, null);
INSERT INTO e_demo2_tab VALUES(e_demo2_tab_sq.nextval, 11, 13, null);
INSERT INTO e_demo2_tab VALUES(e_demo2_tab_sq.nextval, 11, 16, null);
INSERT INTO e_demo2_tab VALUES(e_demo2_tab_sq.nextval, 11, 15, null);
INSERT INTO e_demo2_tab VALUES(e_demo2_tab_sq.nextval, 11, 14, null);
INSERT INTO e_demo2_tab VALUES(e_demo2_tab_sq.nextval, 11, 14, null);
INSERT INTO e_demo2_tab VALUES(e_demo2_tab_sq.nextval, 11, 15, null);
INSERT INTO e_demo2_tab VALUES(e_demo2_tab_sq.nextval, 11, 16, null);
```

Query to load the sequence for `e_uuid` 13 & 15

```
merge into e_demo2_tab a
      using (select
               rowid rid,
               row_number() over (partition by e_id, e_uuid order by rowid) rn
             from e_demo2_tab where e_uuid in(13,15)
            ) x
    on (a.rowid = x.rid)
    when matched then update set a.seq_cnt = x.rn;
```

Then I want to merge into the same table for `e_uuid` 14 & 16
For 14: It should check `e_uuid` = 13 and maximum `seq_cnt`. Here(after executing my merge statement) maximum `seq_cnt` is 2 then the `seq_cnt` for 14 will come as 3 & 4. And if there are any null values then need to give by default 1 in `seq_cnt`

For 16: It should check `e_uuid` = 15 and maximum `seq_cnt`. Here(after executing my merge statement) maximum `seq_cnt` is 2 then the `seq_cnt` for 16 will come as 3 & 4.

Output after executing the merge statement given above

```
+--------+------+--------+---------+
| TAB_ID | E_ID | E_UUID | SEQ_CNT |
+--------+------+--------+---------+
|      1 | 11   |     13 | 1       |
|      2 | 11   |     13 | 2       |
|      3 | 11   |     16 | null    |
|      4 | 11`  |     15 | 1       |
|      5 | 11   |     14 | null    |
|      6 | 11   |     14 | null    |
|      7 | 11   |     15 | 2       |
|      8 | 11   |     16 | null    |
+--------+------+--------+---------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+--------+------+--------+---------+
| TAB_ID | E_ID | E_UUID | SEQ_CNT |
+--------+------+--------+---------+
|      1 | 11   |     13 |       1 |
|      2 | 11   |     13 |       2 |
|      3 | 11   |     16 |       3 |
|      4 | 11`  |     15 |       1 |
|      5 | 11   |     14 |       3 |
|      6 | 11   |     14 |       4 |
|      7 | 11   |     15 |       2 |
|      8 | 11   |     16 |       4 |
+--------+------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Are you basically wanting to do the row_number over a partition of e_id and two consecutive e_uuids? E.g. if you were inserting rows for e_uuids of 19 and 20, would they be grouped together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to group an odd and a consecutive even e_uuid together, you could always change the `partition by` clause to group on `ceil(e_uuid/2)`, like so:

```
merge into e_demo2_tab a
      using (select
               rowid rid,
               row_number() over (partition by e_id, ceil(e_uuid/2) order by e_uuid, rowid) rn
             from e_demo2_tab) x
    on (a.rowid = x.rid)
    when matched then update set a.seq_cnt = x.rn;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3a11b91fa66797baf1319e46b13e504d)

This works because 13/2 = 6.5, and the ceiling value of 6.5 = 7. 14/2 = 7, the ceiling value of which is also 7, since it's already an integer. That makes 13 and 14 grouped together - same logic applies to 15 and 16 - the ceiling of them divided by two comes to 8 for both values.

So that explains the logic behind grouping them together (13 is odd, and 14 is the next consecutive even number).

The rows are then ordered by e_uuid, and then rowid to get the ordering you were after.

If you are only ever concerned about the 13, 14, 15, and 16 e_uuids, you might want to have a filter in your x subquery of `where e_uuid in (13, 14, 15, 16)`, depending on if there are other values of e_uuid in your table.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround but its not even odd. It was just a sample data and I have other e_uuid as well that are based on this concept only. Can we do this using ```CASE expression```

Comment: It's always best to make sure your sample data covers the various scenarios that might occur with your data. Plus an explanation explaining the logic of how the seq_cnt should be updated. Maybe you can use a CASE expression, but as of now, I don't know the logic behind your requirements. Please update your question, and add in the extra information that would allow us to follow what it is you're trying to do and why; remember that we know nothing about your data or your business logic!

Comment: If we can use CASE expression then it would be fine and for getting the seq_cnt I have explained in the original question. Please do let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: You haven't mentioned why it is you have picked 13 and 14 to group together and 15 and 16. If it's not consecutive pairs, how are we meant to know how you want to group your data together? Without that information, it's hard to come up with the logic that might go in a CASE expression

Comment: I have picked 13 and 15 and given the seq_cnt for these two e_uuid only. Now I need to give seq_cnt for 14 & 16. Then for 14 requirement is like I need to check maximum seq_cnt of 13 and accordingly need to update 14 e_uuid seq_cnt. For example, in my test cases for e_uuid 13 I have seq_cnt as 1,2 then for 14 seq_cnt will come 3 & 4 because there are two occurrences for 14. Likewise for 16, here I need to compare e_uuid 15

Comment: yes, but could a group consist of more than two e_uuids? e.g. could 13, 14, and 15 be a group, and 17, 18 be another group, and 20, 22, 26 yet another? What's the logic behind the grouping?

Comment: @Boenist No. Actually 13 is for source and 15 is target so this will not change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241825/discussion-between-boneist-and-vicky).